# Do people who don't do video editing or gaming need anything more than an entry level CPU?

Tags: cpu, computer-building

Someone asked me to help him pick a laptop to buy, he doesn't play games or do video editing. He will only use it to do office work (PowerPoint and Word), browse the internet and watch movies, I don't think any of these things require a powerful CPU and I think he should get a laptop with an entry level CPU like an Intel Celeron or AMD A-series but I am worried that I might be missing something here.

Comment: While there are other things for which you want a good CPU people like him aren't doing them, either.  Base CPU, although I would put a decent amount of RAM in any machine.

Answer (score 2):

Entry level CPU's or APUs work perfectly for most people like this.

The only exception is if you have someone who keeps the same laptop who 10+ years (and yes, I know people who did that because change was annoying) or very impatient people.

The last because a system with a faster CPU is slightly more responsive. And some people get annoyed when firefox takes 0.4 seconds to start rather than 0.3 seconds. But for most of the people those tasks are fine with a entry level CPU or APU. Just enough RAM (say 4GiB, no need to get 8 or 16) and if you have spare budget go for an SSD or a good wireless setup (e.g. laptop with .ac card and a .ac access point). Not more CPU power.

[Edit] several years later. The default memory is now 8GiB rather than 4GiB RAM for entry level.

Comment: I thought that loading programs depended on the HDD or SDD speed not the processor ?

Comment: It depends on both. If the HDD is too slow to provide the data a fast CPU will not help because it has not yet got the data to parse. If the storage is very fast and the CPU extremely slow the disk will be idle a lot while the CPU crunches the data. In practise the HDD was always the bottleneck.

Comment: The first sentence of your third paragraph needs some love.

Comment: Make that the whole third paragraph.